# Hibernate unable to instantiate default tuplizer - cannot find getter

Tags: java, hibernate, tuplizer

I'm trying to use Hibernate to persist a class that looks like this:

```
public class Item implements Serializable, Comparable<Item> {

// Item id
private Integer id;

// Description of item in inventory
private String description;

// Number of items described by this inventory item
private int count;

 //Category item belongs to 
private String category;

// Date item was purchased 
private GregorianCalendar purchaseDate;

    public Item() {
}

    public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

    public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}   

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public GregorianCalendar getPurchaseDate() {
    return purchaseDate;
}

public void setPurchasedate(GregorianCalendar purchaseDate) {
    this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
}
```

My Hibernate mapping file contains the following:

```
<property name="puchaseDate" type="java.util.GregorianCalendar">
  <column name="purchase_date"></column>
</property>
```

When I try to run, I get error messages indicating there is no getter function for the purchaseDate attribute:

```
577 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
577 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
577 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
592 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/home_inventory
592 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
1078 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.1.45
1078 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.12 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
1103 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
1107 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader - Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
1109 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
1110 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
1110 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
1110 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
1110 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
1110 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
1111 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
1112 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1113 [main] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1113 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
1113 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
1113 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
1113 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
1113 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
1113 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
1114 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
1117 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
1118 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
1118 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
1118 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
1118 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
1118 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
1151 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at service.HibernateSessionFactory.currentSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:53)
    at service.ItemSvcHibImpl.generateReport(ItemSvcHibImpl.java:78)
    at service.test.ItemSvcTest.testGenerateReport(ItemSvcTest.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:107)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for puchaseDate in class domain.Item
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
    ... 34 more
```

I'm new to Hibernate, so I don't know all the ins and outs, but I do have the getter and setter for the purchaseDate attribute.  I don't know what I'm missing here - does anyone else?

Answer (score 35):

It came to me once without any typos. I've added **javassist.jar** to classpath and it solved the problem.

Comment: This error occured to me working with the M2Eclipse Maven Plugin for Eclipse, after adding a dependency to hibernate 3.6.4. That dependency was obviously not sufficient. I had to add another dependency to javassist, too. Thanks for the hint, smentek.

Answer (score 16):

Further on down the stack trace, it says this:

```
missing a getter for puchaseDate
```

You might want to check for typos ;) You're missing an R and setPurchasedate should be setPurchaseDate

Comment: OK, I knew I was missing something stupid - I just didn't expect it to be THAT stupid.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I had the same problems with the camelCasing on a setter. Fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem--this particular error message was preceded by *another* saying I didn't have getter/setters setup right...

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the problem is probably in the capitalization:  `setPurchasedate()` should be `setPurchaseDate()` (with a capital "D").

Answer (score 4):

If it can help someone:

In my case there were **errors in my mapping files**. Classes were not referenced by their full package names. I did this mistake because I generated the mappings when my bean classes belonged to the default package (hence no package name; e.g.: `Order` instead of `com.mypackage.Order`) and then I moved my bean classes to package (in the example `com.mypackage`). Unfortunately mapping files did not changed accordingly with the new package definition.

My hint is redo Hibernate reverse engineering and see what it produces, comparing it with your current mapping files.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me, you just saved me a headache. I had javassist already, and all the other solutions something wrong in their getters/setters, and I couldn't figure out where that problem was for me in my files. I just reverse engineered to get what it should be, and that did the trick. :D

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to method name,It is **case sensitive**!

In my case,it could not recognize getter very well; my property name was `uId` and I used `getUId` name for getter name and when I changed it to `getuId` problem solved!

Comment: Soo true.  Its lot easier to have eclipse generate getters and setters instead of manually writing them.

Answer (score 3):

I included java assit.jar and it worked

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the

```
Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
```

because I had a momentary lapse of donkeyness when renaming a field on a POJO that I had previously mapped.

I changed the Java attribute name with my trusty IDE refactor hotkey, which does *not* also change the getter & setter method names.  I changed the getter (because it caught my attention with its @Column annotation that I also needed to address because the table column name was changing).

I neglected, however, to change the setter, and that was the cause of the error.