# MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have already read other topics related to my problem, but unfortunately i cant found any solution.

I have 2 tables named: cliente and localServico

I have programmed 3 different class: 
Cliente
LocalServico

and

Endereco which is a super class of Cliente and LocalServico.

When I mapped my Cliente.hbm.xml as made as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 29/07/2015 20:14:34 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Cliente" table="cliente" schema="public" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idcliente" type="int">
            <column name="idcliente" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="nome" type="string">
            <column name="nome" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="nomefantasia" type="string">
            <column name="nomefantasia" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="tipofj" type="string">
            <column name="tipofj" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="cnpjcpf" type="string">
            <column name="cnpjcpf" length="14" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="cep" type="string">
            <column name="cep" length="8" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="endereco" type="string">
            <column name="endereco" length="40" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="numeroendereco" type="string">
            <column name="numeroendereco" length="5" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="complemento" type="string">
            <column name="complemento" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="proximidade" type="string">
            <column name="proximidade" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="bairro" type="string">
            <column name="bairro" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="estado" type="string">
            <column name="estado" length="2" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="telefone1" type="string">
            <column name="telefone1" length="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="telefone2" type="string">
            <column name="telefone2" length="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="telefone3" type="string">
            <column name="telefone3" length="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="situacao" type="string">
            <column name="situacao" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
         <many-to-one name="rota" class="model.Rota" fetch="select">
            <column name="idrota" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

whole properties above is regarding both class, Cliente and the super class Endereco.

when I start the program I got the following Error:

```
Informações:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para o contexto '/nutrisys'
Informações:   Monitoring jndi:/server/nutrisys/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Informações:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
Informações:   Loading application [nutrisys] at [/nutrisys]
Informações:   nutrisys was successfully deployed in 15.771 milliseconds.
Informações:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Informações:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Informações:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Informações:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Informações:   HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Informações:   HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
WARN:   HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Informações:   HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: model/Usuario.hbm.xml
Informações:   HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: model/Grupo.hbm.xml
Informações:   HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: model/Rota.hbm.xml
Informações:   HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: model/Cliente.hbm.xml
Informações:   HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
WARN:   HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Informações:   HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nutrisys]
Informações:   HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
Informações:   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Informações:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Informações:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Informações:   HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Informações:   HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Informações:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Grave:   Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Advertência:   ${usuarioManager.logar}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
javax.faces.FacesException: ${usuarioManager.logar}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at dao.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:30)
    at dao.util.Conn.abreConexao(Conn.java:38)
    at dao.UsuarioDao.buscarPorNomeAtivo(UsuarioDao.java:67)
    at control.UsuarioManager.logar(UsuarioManager.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at dao.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:26)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for numeroendereco in class model.Cliente
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    ... 68 more

Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at dao.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:30)
    at dao.util.Conn.abreConexao(Conn.java:38)
    at dao.UsuarioDao.buscarPorNomeAtivo(UsuarioDao.java:67)
    at control.UsuarioManager.logar(UsuarioManager.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at dao.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:26)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for numeroendereco in class model.Cliente
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    ... 68 more

Advertência:   The web application [/nutrisys] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Informações:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para o contexto '/nutrisys'
Informações:   Monitoring jndi:/server/nutrisys/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Informações:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
Informações:   Loading application [nutrisys] at [/nutrisys]
Informações:   nutrisys was successfully deployed in 19.204 milliseconds.
```

Comment: This can result from a javassist jar classpath issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669724/hibernate-unable-to-instantiate-default-tuplizer-cannot-find-getter

Answer (score 2):

In the last stack trace, there is no getter for numeroendereco in your model. Try to make it and see the next stack trace

Answer (score 0):

heello my friend.

thanks for your answer!

the getter and setter for numeroendereco is correctly declared on Super Class Endereco.

see below my class Endereco:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package model;

/**
 *
 * @author Vinicius Lemos
 */

public abstract class Endereco implements java.io.Serializable {

private String cep;
private String endereco;
private String numeroEndereco;
private String complemento;
private String proximidade;
private String bairro;
private String estado;
private String telefone1;
private String telefone2;
private String telefone3;
private String email;
private Rota rota;

    public Endereco(){

    }
    public Endereco(String cep, String endereco, String numeroEndereco, String complemento, String proximidade, String bairro, String estado, String telefone1, String telefone2, String telefone3, String email,Rota rota) {
        this.cep = cep;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.numeroEndereco = numeroEndereco;
        this.complemento = complemento;
        this.proximidade = proximidade;
        this.bairro = bairro;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.telefone1 = telefone1;
        this.telefone2 = telefone2;
        this.telefone3 = telefone3;
        this.email = email;
        this.rota = rota;
    }


    /**
     * @return the cep
     */
    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    /**
     * @param cep the cep to set
     */
    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    /**
     * @return the endereco
     */
    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    /**
     * @param endereco the endereco to set
     */
    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numeroEndereco
     */
    public String getNumeroEndereco() {
        return numeroEndereco;
    }

    /**
     * @param numeroEndereco the numeroEndereco to set
     */
    public void setNumeroEndereco(String numeroEndereco) {
        this.numeroEndereco = numeroEndereco;
    }

    /**
     * @return the complemento
     */
    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    /**
     * @param complemento the complemento to set
     */
    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    /**
     * @return the proximidade
     */
    public String getProximidade() {
        return proximidade;
    }

    /**
     * @param proximidade the proximidade to set
     */
    public void setProximidade(String proximidade) {
        this.proximidade = proximidade;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bairro
     */
    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    /**
     * @param bairro the bairro to set
     */
    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    /**
     * @return the estado
     */
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    /**
     * @param estado the estado to set
     */
    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefone1
     */
    public String getTelefone1() {
        return telefone1;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefone1 the telefone1 to set
     */
    public void setTelefone1(String telefone1) {
        this.telefone1 = telefone1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefone2
     */
    public String getTelefone2() {
        return telefone2;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefone2 the telefone2 to set
     */
    public void setTelefone2(String telefone2) {
        this.telefone2 = telefone2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefone3
     */
    public String getTelefone3() {
        return telefone3;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefone3 the telefone3 to set
     */
    public void setTelefone3(String telefone3) {
        this.telefone3 = telefone3;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rota
     */
    public Rota getRota() {
        return rota;
    }

    /**
     * @param rota the rota to set
     */
    public void setRota(Rota rota) {
        this.rota = rota;
    }

}
```

and now my Class Cliente

```
package model;
// Generated 29/07/2015 20:14:20 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1



/**
 * Cliente generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Cliente extends Endereco implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int idcliente;
     private String nome;
     private String nomefantasia;
     private String tipofj;
     private String cnpjcpf;
     private String situacao;


    public Cliente() {
    }


    public Cliente(int idcliente, String nome, String nomefantasia, String tipofj, String cnpjcpf, String situacao) {
        this.idcliente = idcliente;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.nomefantasia = nomefantasia;
        this.tipofj = tipofj;
        this.cnpjcpf = cnpjcpf;
        this.situacao = situacao;
    }
    public Cliente(int idcliente, String nome, String nomefantasia, String tipofj, String cnpjcpf, String cep, String endereco, String numeroendereco, String complemento, String proximidade, String bairro, String estado, String telefone1, String telefone2, String telefone3, String email, String situacao, Rota rota) {
       this.idcliente = idcliente;
       this.nome = nome;
       this.nomefantasia = nomefantasia;
       this.tipofj = tipofj;
       this.cnpjcpf = cnpjcpf;
       this.situacao = situacao;
       this.setCep(cep);
       this.setEndereco(endereco);
       this.setNumeroEndereco(numeroendereco);
       this.setComplemento(complemento);
       this.setProximidade(proximidade);
       this.setBairro(bairro);
       this.setEstado(estado);
       this.setTelefone1(telefone1);
       this.setTelefone2(telefone2);
       this.setTelefone3(telefone3);
       this.setEmail(email);
       this.setRota(rota);
    }

    public int getIdcliente() {
        return this.idcliente;
    }

    public void setIdcliente(int idcliente) {
        this.idcliente = idcliente;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getNomefantasia() {
        return this.nomefantasia;
    }

    public void setNomefantasia(String nomefantasia) {
        this.nomefantasia = nomefantasia;
    }
    public String getTipofj() {
        return this.tipofj;
    }

    public void setTipofj(String tipofj) {
        this.tipofj = tipofj;
    }
    public String getCnpjcpf() {
        return this.cnpjcpf;
    }

    public void setCnpjcpf(String cnpjcpf) {
        this.cnpjcpf = cnpjcpf;
    }

    public String getSituacao() {
        return this.situacao;
    }

    public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
        this.situacao = situacao;
    }





}
```